# Thunderbird multiple process -no-remote and http-links

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, process

Whenever I click a Link in thunderbird which was started with the -no-remote option and firefox is running, I get a "Firefox is already running ... " error message.

Is there a way to prevent this error message and have firefox (in a running instance) open a new tab?